# perlcritic: Does not validate syntax

Tags: perl

I noticed that `perlcritic` (`Perl::Critic`) does not appear to care about mismatched parens in `if` statements, as an example. But it does seem to care (on lower severity settings) about a *lot* of things.

To me, it seems useless if it can't even tell me that I have a simple syntax problem like mismatched parens. Is this how it is designed to work?

Comment: `perl -c script.pl` will run a syntax check.  Not sure why `Perl::Critic` would duplicate that.

Comment: `perl -c` can notify you of syntax issues. `perlcritic` is a lint program, not a compiler.

Comment: `perl -c` has a "[vulnerability](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/77)"

Comment: [Perl::Critic](http://p3rl/Perl::Critic) starts with the assumption that you gave it a compilable program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is how Perl::Critic works.

I'm not sure if it was explicitly designed that way, but rather compiling Perl code is so trivial it wasn't even considered.  It also doesn't know how to build your Perl code, if it needs to set any library paths or whatnot, so that would add extra configuration complexity.  Also, compiling Perl code can execute Perl code so it becomes a security issue.

However, it cannot operate correctly on code which does not compile.  So you're best to compile the code before linting.

For syntax checking you can use `perl -c <your program>`.  For more systematic checks, you can write a test using [Test::Compile](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aCompile).  Put it into `t/00compile.t`.  You can then use [Test::Perl::Critic](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aPerl%3a%3aCritic) to test your code does not violate your standards.  Put that into `t/00critic.t` and it will run after the compile check.

Comment: The `perl -c ...` option is a great idea.  Another trick that can bring pairing mismatches into stark relief is `perltidy`.  FWIW: My editor is set up to run both `perl -c ...` and `Perl::Critic` whenever I pause for a bit.